# How to wrap mat-list-item in mat-button in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have a list and I would that every element of the list become clickable with a ripple effect like mat-button component.

I tried this :

```
<mat-list role="list" *ngFor="let userS of Projet?.backlog.userStory; let i=index">
    <button mat-button>
        <mat-list-item role="listitem">User Story #{{i}} : {{userS.userStory}} </mat-list-item>
    </button>
</mat-list>
```

But I that's don't working element are not clickable .

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: I'm don't getting errors

Comment: Check that a `mat-button` will work properly outside of `<mat-list>`.

Comment: Oh it was working from the beginning I  was looking at the false component..

Comment: I there any reason why the button is missing a type? try to assign a type to the button and run a test again. e.g. `<button mat-button type="submit">User Story #{{i}} : {{userS.userStory}}</button>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put the `<button>` inside the `<mat-list-item>`.  Not sure if this will help because I think the button should still work the way you have it.

```
<mat-list role="list">
    <mat-list-item role="listitem"> 
       <button mat-button>
          User Story #{{i}} : {{userS.userStory}}       
       </button>
     </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Button list items are now directly supported**

Action lists are now available, and let you render a list with buttons as the list item element.  Simply change the parent component to `mat-action-list` and use a `button` with the `mat-list-item` directive!

https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview#action-lists

```
<!-- Example is from https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview#action-lists -->
<mat-action-list>
  <button mat-list-item (click)="save()"> Save </button>
  <button mat-list-item (click)="undo()"> Undo </button>
</mat-action-list>
```

Comment: As of 2022, this is the correct answer.